# Javascript: Insert item into an the exact center of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

Apologies if this is an asked/answered thing, but I did a general search and couldn't find the result I was looking for.

Say I've got an array, but I don't know the length of it, for whatever reason. I want to insert items into the array at an exact position (in this case, the center)

For the purposes of this question, I'll provide the array and how I got the output to read properly..

```
function insertIntoMiddle(array, item) {
    array.splice(4, 2, item);
    return array.sort();
}


const items = insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2);
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2), '<-- should be [1 , 2 , 3]');
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3, 7, 9], 5), '<-- should be [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]');
```

And we get an output of:

```
 [1, 2, 3] <-- should be [1 , 2 , 3] 
 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] <-- should be [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Which is as it should be.. But my question is, what if, for whatever reason, say it's a database that's being read into an array for manipulation, and over time the database has grown. We don't know how long the array is..But we still want to insert into the EXACT middle of the array.. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: If you sort it anyway, then you're not `insertIntoMiddle`

Comment: what about odd length' arrays?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking how to insert into the midpoint of an Array, at a specific insertion point, or at a point at which the item would be sorted.

Comment: please supply the data format, you are refering

Answer (score 0):

You could splice it with the half of the length.

```js
function insertIntoMiddle(array, item) {
    array.splice(array.length >> 1, 0, item);
    return array
}

console.log(...insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2));
console.log(...insertIntoMiddle([1, 3, 7, 9], 5));
```

Comment: OP says `but I don't know the length of it, for whatever reason`.  Not sure how academic this question is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointers, move first with +2 and second with +1, untill the end.

when the first one is at the end second one will be at the middle.

Insert the item at the position of second pointer.

```js
function insertIntoMiddle(array, item) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while (array[i]) {
    i += 2;
    j++;
  }
  array.splice(j, 0, item);
  return array;
}

console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3, 7, 9], 5));
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It never dawned on me to use 2 pointers. I'm still learning, so this was more of a "what if" as I was learning how to splice arrays..  thank you!

Comment: np, this question actually is more suitable with Linkedlist or the data structures with no length properties. you will see these types of problems more in DS.